# Java parse DateTime and ignore timezone

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, java-time

I need to parse a date string that is in the following format.

> "2016-05-19 13:07:15 PDT"

My database server is in ET, but I want to store the TIMESTAMP `2016-05-19 13:07:15` in my database, without the timezone and without converting it to ET. So, essentially, I want to ignore the PDT in the string.

Currently, I parse my string to a `ZonedDateTime` object and map that to a TIMESTAMP data type in my database, but hibernate is doing some conversion on the back end, since it knows that my `ZonedDateTime` is in PDT. So, the date in the example above ends up getting stored in my database as `2016-05-19 16:07:15` instead of what I want, `2016-05-19 13:07:15`.

One idea I had thought of was to just strip the PDT off of the end of the string, then parse it as a `LocalDateTime`, but before I do that, I was going to see if there was any way to essentially just ignore the timezone from a `ZonedDateTime`, or parse the string shown above to a `LocalDateTime` (or some other java time object that doesn't care about time zone) without actually doing the conversion from PDT to ET.

Is there any way to acheive this without actually pulling the timezone off of the string before parsing?

Comment: There seem to be quite a few StackOverflow questions and answers that describe how to parse Date Strings while ignoring timezones. Have you tried any of them? What didn't work?

Comment: There seem to be quite a few in C# and quite a few that do not reference the java.time API. If you could find one that uses java.time, it would be wonderful if you could post a link to it.

Comment: Actually, I think your question and the accepted answer are one of the better versions, especially because Java 8 was released in 2014 so some older answers are more complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
String datestring = "2016-05-19 13:07:15 PDT";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz");

LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.from(formatter.parse(datestring));
System.out.println(localDateTime);
// Output: 2016-05-19T13:07:15
```

Edit: As an alternative, if you already have a `ZonedDateTime` Object, this also works (and removes the timezone):

```
LocalDateTime.from(zonedDateTime);
```

Comment: Ah, this does work. I assumed that parsing it as a `LocalDateTime` would automatically convert it to ET, since the server's local time is ET, and that I would get `2016-05-19 16:07:15`, but it does give me exactly what I want. Thanks.

Comment: Also, I ended up using this alternative way: `LocalDateTime.parse(datestring, formatter);`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with Date and Time in different timezones is to store the Date and Time in`UTC (GMT +0)` , and at the time of retrieval, based on the requester it should be converted to desired timezone. This will help you to expand the date time feature in future if you have to deal with multiple Time zones.